# run script at termination of process

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services

I'm computing on a AWS EC2 type environment. I have a script that runs on the headnode, then executes a shell command on a VM which it detachs from the headnode parent shell.

headnode.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
...
nohup ssh -i vm-key ubuntu@vm-ip './vm_script.sh' &
exit 0
```

The reason I do it like this, is that the vm_script takes a very long time to finish. So I want to detach it from the headnode shell, and have it run in the background of the VM.

vm_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
...
ssh -i head-node-key user@head-node-ip './delete-vm.sh'
exit 0
```

Once the VM completes the task it sends a command back to the headnode to delete the VM.

Is there a more reliable way to execute the final script on the headnode following completion of the script on the VM?

E.g., After I launch the vm_script.sh, could I launch another script on the headnode that waits for the completion of the PID on the VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you trust in the network link, the more general reliable way is the simpler way. I would rewrite `headnode.sh` as presented below:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
ssh -i vm-key ubuntu@vm-ip './vm_script.sh' && ./delete-vm.sh
```

The script above waits the termination of `vm_script.sh` and then invokes `./delete-vm.sh` if no error code is returned by `vm_script.sh`.

If you don't want to be stuck in the shell waiting for the termination of `headnode.sh`, just call it using `nohup ./headnode.sh &`

Comment: Great idea. Thank you.